# Rails: How to redirect to a static page if user is using IE 7 or less?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't want IE 7 users to use the website. It may not be a good idea, but I don't mind turning away users. How do I redirect users using IE 7 or less to a static page and stop them from using my website? Currently, I have this code in my `application.html.erb` which redirects the user to an external site. But, I'd like it to redirect it to a static page within my app:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=http://www.google.com">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition in application view

```
<% if params[:controller] != "static_pages_controller" %>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=<%= static_pages_url %>">
  <![endif]--> 
<% end %>
```

Here assuming that index method inside the static_pages controller is the static page.